# Knockout JS data-bind if text equals set attr class?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm looking to have an conditional binding for the css class based off of the text value.

```
<div class="modal-body" data-bind="foreach: messageList">
    <div class="talk-bubble tri-right" data-bind="attr: { css: ko.unwrap(outFrom) === 'outGoing' ? 'right-top' : 'left-top' }">
          <div class="talktext">
               <p data-bind="text: message"></p>
               <span data-bind="text: date"></span>
               <span data-bind="text: outFrom"></span>
               <input data-bind="value: message_number" />
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your problem? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest just to have a separate rule for each.

```
<div class="modal-body" data-bind="foreach: messageList">
    <div class="talk-bubble tri-right" data-bind="
        css: { 
            'right-top': outFrom() === 'outGoing',
            'left-top' : outFrom() !== 'outGoing'
        }">
        <div class="talktext">
            <p data-bind="text: message"></p>
            <span data-bind="text: date"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: outFrom"></span>
            <input data-bind="value: message_number" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Substitute ko.unwrap(outFrom) if outFrom may or may not be observable.

You could also put a function on message that returns the class name and do

```
data-bind="css: functionThatReturnsClassName"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked and also thanks for the tip on using a function to return back the needed value.